# How do I find all references without "peeking"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to see all references in a bottom-docked window (similar to how to the "Problems" window appears). I am trying to find all references to a function so that I can then jump to each place I am using the function and make changes. The current "peek" feature makes this very inconvenient to do. For example:

First I find all references of `getStartDate`
[image]

The inline "peek" window appears and shows me the reference in the current file, along with others. I click on another reference:
[image]

The editor navigates to that file and splits the file in half in order to display... the file I am already editing. Please tell me there is a way to dock this window to the bottom of the screen. Or better yet, that there is a "full" find all references as opposed to a "peek" find all references.

Comment: You could just do a search across files (the magnifying icon) and then in the explorer bar is your list of function references, clicking on those opens a new editor tab.  Seems like pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1.22 changed how to go to references across files, see [navigating to references across files](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_error-and-reference-navigation-across-files) .  At least it doesn't do the editor splitting you describe - you can just cycle through the references going to each file in its already opened editor in turn.

You can <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> through the references, and then <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> to go that reference in another file.

Comment: Thank goodness. The old way was an extreme case of "too clever for its own good" UX